# ava.io.IOException: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)

Tags: java, android

My project is a download manager . when I want to give a link to download , It gives me error.
I think my promlem is that Cant not find the link to download but I can not find the my mistake.
here is my code:

```
@Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            URL url = new URL(mission.url);
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            mission.length = conn.getContentLength();

            if (mission.length <= 0) {
                mission.errCode = DownloadMission.ERROR_SERVER_UNSUPPORTED;
                //mission.notifyError(DownloadMission.ERROR_SERVER_UNSUPPORTED);
                return;
            }

            // Open again
            conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setRequestProperty("Range", "bytes=" + (mission.length - 10) + "-" + mission.length);

            if (conn.getResponseCode() != 206) {
                // Fallback to single thread if no partial content support
                mission.fallback = true;

                if (DEBUG) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "falling back");
                }
            }

            if (DEBUG) {
                Log.d(TAG, "response = " + conn.getResponseCode());
            }

            mission.blocks = mission.length / BLOCK_SIZE;

            if (mission.threadCount > mission.blocks) {
                mission.threadCount = (int) mission.blocks;
            }

            if (mission.threadCount <= 0) {
                mission.threadCount = 1;
            }

            if (mission.blocks * BLOCK_SIZE < mission.length) {
                mission.blocks++;
            }


            new File(mission.location).mkdirs();
            new File(mission.location + "/" + mission.name).createNewFile();
            RandomAccessFile af = new RandomAccessFile(mission.location + "/" + mission.name, "rw");
            af.setLength(mission.length);
            af.close();

            mission.start();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Notify
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
```

This where that get the url .
any suggestion?

Comment: both `mkdirs()` and `createNewFile()` returns boolean, to tell if success, have you checked those returned values? i.e was the file/directory created? one more thing, print the value of `mission.location + "/" + mission.name` and see if it's a valid path

Comment: how to print them?

Comment: `Log.i(), Log.d()` .. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Log.html

Comment: nothing was shown :-(

Comment: if you are sure, then the path is not valid, thus no dir/file were created. you can use the Log to show the result of mkdir and createfile too, see if it's true or false, it shuld be false then. you need to trace the path and filename variables and see why they are not filled

Comment: Now I found that i get errors just in android 6 , the other is ok