# open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory in android 6

Tags: java, android

I want to download a link with my project.

I cant file right location so I got this error.

```
 open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
```

first I search it and I understand that I have this problem just in android 6 or above. and my code works in android 5 correctly.I found lot of things about run time permission that in android 6 I need run time permission so I try to check my permission and request them . but when I check the permission It shows that i already have these permission.
So this way is not right.
this is my code:

```
public void run() {
        try {
            URL url = new URL(mission.url);
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            mission.length = conn.getContentLength();

            if (mission.length <= 0) {
                mission.errCode = DownloadMission.ERROR_SERVER_UNSUPPORTED;
                //mission.notifyError(DownloadMission.ERROR_SERVER_UNSUPPORTED);
                return;
            }

            // Open again
            conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setRequestProperty("Range", "bytes=" + (mission.length - 10) + "-" + mission.length);

            if (conn.getResponseCode() != 206) {
                // Fallback to single thread if no partial content support
                mission.fallback = true;

                if (DEBUG) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "falling back");
                }
            }

            if (DEBUG) {
                Log.d(TAG, "response = " + conn.getResponseCode());
            }

            mission.blocks = mission.length / BLOCK_SIZE;

            if (mission.threadCount > mission.blocks) {
                mission.threadCount = (int) mission.blocks;
            }

            if (mission.threadCount <= 0) {
                mission.threadCount = 1;
            }

            if (mission.blocks * BLOCK_SIZE < mission.length) {
                mission.blocks++;
            }


            new File(mission.location).mkdirs();
            new File(mission.location + "/" + mission.name).createNewFile();
            RandomAccessFile af = new RandomAccessFile(mission.location + "/" + mission.name, "rw");
            af.setLength(mission.length);
            af.close();
            mission.start();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Notify

            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
```

i got error exactly in this line:

```
   new File(mission.location + "/" + mission.name).createNewFile();
```

and this line:

```
 throw new RuntimeException(e);
```

I check this path and it exist:

```
mission.location + "/" + mission.name
```

any help?
I have two question now:
1.Is my problem is related to permission ? if so where I must checked them (i checked in my first activity )
2.althought my path is right why I have this error?

```
   open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
```

Comment: `want to download a link with my project. But I got this error : open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)`. Your problem has nothing to do with downloading a file. Your problem is that you cannot create a file at the file system. Please adapt your post as now it's very confusing. Remove all irrelevant code please.

Comment: I told that this works in android 5 correctly.i try to explain simple

Comment: SImple would be if you only had one statement. The one that tries to create a file.

Comment: ok now i will edit it and here is my problem again,http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43568764/ava-io-ioexception-open-failed-enoent-no-such-file-or-directory?noredirect=1#comment74188047_43568764